# Mysql database design for online exam

Tags: php, mysql

Im creating an optimized database for online exam module.

I have two choices:

- Schema with which Im storing the question, options and answer in same row.

  Table: questions
  Col: q_id, question, opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4, opt5, ans
- Schema with which Im having 3 different tabled for each operation.

  Table: questions
  Col: q_id, question

  Table: options
  Col: q_id, opt_id, option

  Table answers
  Col: q_id, ans

Comment: If you are creating database, how you know it is optimized? ;]

Comment: I guess he means that he is trying to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

Schema 2 is more along the lines of what you should be aiming for.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a 3rd option:

```
q_id | question | options | answer
```

where the option column is of type text and stores a serialized array or json.

For the 2 options you provided: the 2nd one world be the weapon of choice

Answer (score 0):

I would use schema 2, as it allows you to add an arbitrary amount of answers.

You could however incorporate the answers `table` in the `options` table.

```
q_id | opt_id | option | correct
```

In this way you can also have multiple correct answers per question.

Answer (score 0):

Schema 2 would be the better option if you want to stay flexible in your exam options.

However, if you are sure you can set a fixed amount of questions every time, you might want to consider putting table "questions" and "options" into one and just having the answers vary for each user.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a fixed number of answers schema 1 would be better

but if the question may have  any number of answers this would be better

```
question_id,question,answer_id_of_the_solution

answer_id,question_id,answer
```